# Screens in LAN?

Tags: display, lan

I need to connect about twenty (~10 inch) screens (or photo digital frames) next to each other, and display photos and videos in each one. Those photos and videos would be in a LAN server, and every screen should be configured what photos and videos to show from a central computer.

How could I have 20 screens in LAN?

Comment: It depends on how you can control Your "screens" over LAN. (I use screens in quotes, because simple dumb screens don't have LAN connection.

Comment: For example, if you can force "screens" to open url in browser and browser  support video and java-script, then possible control it from some kind central web app.

Comment: thanks. If screens can display pictures and videos in its own way (not browser-based) is enough. The big deal for me is how could I feed them individually, through a computer in which a software is able to select media for each screen.

Comment: Yes it main problem "how control Your <screens> remotely". But there no universal solution.
Other ex.: Suspect this "screen" Linux based, then may be You can hack in shell and may be get remote control.

Comment: (hopefully from a LAN server. In order to reproduce the same setup in another place)

Comment: Define what kind of screen You want to use. If it Android Tablet, then highly possible remote dispay app already in Play market.

Comment: Yes. First, I should be able to "drive" all screens into a computer. Maybe certain digital photo frames includes Ethernet input.

Comment: Tablets could be a better option, you're right.

Comment: Look like You seek for "media advertising box" solution (it special platform for doing what You describe at industrial scale). If You planning use for it cheap media frame, You probably need to hack it for remote control.

Comment: Actually, yes. I couldn't find any solution, plus I didn't know what keywords use. I'll try again with something like "media advertising box", otherwise I'll use tablets in some way.